# Porting Documentation to SE2.0: Part 2

Tags: discussion

I've read [this question](/q/281689/335772), which seems to have a de facto [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) on it, with bluefeet ♦ saying to wait 6-8 weeks.

It's been 6-8 weeks. (Actually, it's been 4 months.) Let's discuss it again.

To start off, and to ensure that this doesn't get closed as a duplicate of the aforementioned question, here's a few things that I feel need to be discussed:

1. Is this feasible?
2. Obviously not every site should have Documentation; after all, what exactly would [Software Recommendations](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) or [Code Review](//codereview.stackexchange.com) do with it? Thus, **which sites would get Documentation** and **what would new sites need to do to add it?**
3. Should there be a mechanism for migrating topics between sites?
4. Could sites set custom reject reasons?
5. If this is going to be rolled out network-wide, should we clean up the [documentation](/questions/tagged/documentation) tag on Meta.SE, or create a new tag?

Comment: That ''6-8 weeks'' actually means practically 6-8 years, if you missed the meta post bluefeet linked

Comment: I can directly answer your second question: this would not be rolled out to all sites. How these features work is we make them *available* and each community needs to discuss on their Meta whether or not they want to have the feature enabled on their site. If there is a consensus among the community to enable it, then we'd do so for that specific site. A migration mechanism and custom reject reasons are separate feature requests, which warrant their own questions and shouldn't really be merged into a discussion like this. But I'd say a migration feature for Docs is highly unlikely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Documentation is still in beta, so I don't think we need to discuss that again. I think you've taken the phrase "in 6-8 weeks" too seriously. You should read [The Many Memes of Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/310998):

> **Definition**: The time estimate given "off the top of my head" when the Stack Overflow team has only a vague idea of how long a task will take because they have little-to-no formal scheduling or even a list of tasks.

Comment: I know, and have read, that, but I really think that Docs doesn't need to be in beta for much longer. It's been over a month since the last major update. That's definitely a good sign.

Comment: @StephenLeppik Well when you consider we were all in Philadelphia the first week of November, and a lot of people are off for holidays this week. We still haven't even fully released the Discussion feature, which is a pretty huge change that will likely introduce more bugs, etc. Simply put, there is no time frame for how long it will take before we're willing to consider this for other sites. But that time hasn't yet come.

Comment: @StephenLeppik We haven't explicitly discussed a timeline for the end of beta just yet. November was a short month between holidays and the company meetup, as animuson mentioned, and December is gonna have a good chunk lost to holidays as well. I'd handwave-estimate two or three months in beta still, but really it's more of an "as long as it takes" type of thing. (Source: I'm on the Docs team.)